# Какой Bootstrap использовать с Angular 2?

Tags: bootstrap, angular2

Посоветуйте, какой Bootstrap лучше использовать с Angular 2?
Мои копания в Google привели к [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap), но смущает маленький номер версии, к тому же с пометкой альфа.

Подскажите, какой Bootstrap выбрать?

Answer (score 0):

ng-bootstrap неплохо использовать (был опыт, всё нормально работает), но я бы остановился всё-таки на [Angular material](https://material.angular.io/)